# CocoaAsyncSocket and NativeScript issue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm writing a Nativescript Plugin for UDP comms based on CocoaAsyncSocket but my app is crashing when I try to perform any async operation in the context of this pod.
It seems to be something related to the queues/threads on iOS x {N}, but I haven't been able to solve it, any idea?

Here is how I'm creating my Plugin iOS class in Typescript:

```
export class UdpProtocol extends NSObject implements GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate
```

Here is how I'm initialising my `GCDAsyncUdpSocket`:

```
let dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("sendUnicast_queue", null);
let sock = GCDAsyncUdpSocket.alloc()
           .initWithDelegateDelegateQueue(this, dispatchQueue);
```

Here is one example of async method I'm calling in my .ts:

```
sock.sendDataToHostPortWithTimeoutTag(sendData, address, port, -1, this.tag);
```

Here is the callback I was expecting to be correctly fired:

```
udpSocketDidSendDataWithTag(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, tag: number): void {
        console.log('udpSocketDidSendDataWithTag callback');
}
```

But unfortunately what I got is the JS exception below:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///node_modules/@nativescript/core/inspector_modules.js:1:0: Loading inspector modules...
CONSOLE LOG file:///node_modules/@nativescript/core/inspector_modules.js:6:0: Finished loading inspector modules.
NativeScript debugger attached.
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
Native stack trace:
1   0x11033960e NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
2   0x110388f76 -[TNSRuntimeInspector reportFatalError:]
3   0x10fc2d23b TNSInspectorUncaughtExceptionHandler
4   0x7fff23e3a36d __handleUncaughtException
5   0x7fff50ad7c05 _objc_terminate()
6   0x7fff4f926c87 std::__terminate(void (*)())
7   0x7fff4f926c29 std::terminate()
8   0x7fff519128df _dispatch_client_callout
9   0x7fff5191860c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain
10  0x7fff51919044 _dispatch_lane_invoke
11  0x7fff519230c4 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
12  0x7fff51b37a3d _pthread_wqthread
13  0x7fff51b36b77 start_wqthread
JavaScript stack trace:
UIApplicationMain(file:///node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.js:312:0)
at run(file:///node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.js:312:0)
at file:///node_modules/@nativescript/angular/platform-common.js:210:0
at file:///node_modules/@nativescript/angular/platform-common.js:111:0
at file:///node_modules/@nativescript/angular/platform-common.js:91:0
at file:///app/bundle.js:198:144
at ./main.ts(file:///app/bundle.js:203:34)
at __webpack_require__(file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
at checkDeferredModules(file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:43:0)
at webpackJsonpCallback(file:///src/webpack/bootstrap:30:0)
at anonymous(file:///app/bundle.js:2:61)
at evaluate([native code])
at moduleEvaluation([native code])
at [native code]
at asyncFunctionResume([native code])
at [native code]
at promiseReactionJob([native code])
JavaScript error:
file:///node_modules/@nativescript/core/application/application.js:312:0: JS ERROR Error: -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036496c0
NativeScript caught signal 6.
Native Stack:
1   0x11038a251 sig_handler(int)
2   0x7fff51b2f5fd _sigtramp
3   0x7fff51a23f39 itoa64
4   0x7fff51a1fb7c abort
5   0x7fff4f927858 abort_message
6   0x7fff4f926cad std::__terminate(void (*)())
7   0x7fff4f926c29 std::terminate()
8   0x7fff519128df _dispatch_client_callout
9   0x7fff5191860c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain
10  0x7fff51919044 _dispatch_lane_invoke
11  0x7fff519230c4 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
12  0x7fff51b37a3d _pthread_wqthread
13  0x7fff51b36b77 start_wqthread
JS Stack unavailable. Current thread hasn't initialized a {N} runtime.
```

I've already tried solutions like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306672/marshalling-objective-c-to-nativescript-js/51393476), but no success.

The plugin with the angular demo causing the issue is available in [this brach](https://github.com/floripabit/nativescript-ip-protocol/tree/ios)

Any tip or help is very welcomed :)

Comment: I don't see the specific code snippet in the repo you have pointed. Are you sure it's upto date?

Comment: @Manoj it is under iOS branch. The specific file is: https://github.com/floripabit/nativescript-ip-protocol/blob/ios/src/udp/udp.ios.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I've found out that the error was associated to how I was creating *sendData* variable, I've changed it from:

```
let sendData: any = NSString.alloc().initWithCString(msg);
```

to

```
const sendData: NSData = NSData.alloc().initWithBase64EncodedStringOptions(msg, 1);
```